# CAShapeLayer problems - not drawing in nstableview

Tags: macos, nstableview, cashapelayer

I customize a view-based tableview, and in the customize NSView, I write in the init:

```
NSRect testRect = imageViewRect;

CGMutablePathRef roundPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(roundPath, NULL,
             [self arcCenter:testRect].x,
             [self arcCenter:testRect].y,
             ArcRadius,
             2 * M_PI + M_PI_2,
             M_PI_2,
             YES);

self.backgroundLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.backgroundLayer.frame = testRect;
self.backgroundLayer.path = roundPath;
self.backgroundLayer.strokeColor = [[NSColor blueColor] CGColor];
self.backgroundLayer.fillColor = nil;
self.backgroundLayer.lineWidth = 5.0f;
self.backgroundLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
[self.layer addSublayer:self.backgroundLayer];
[self.backgroundLayer setFillColor:[NSColor yellowColor].CGColor];
```

but the layer is not shown, I really don't know where is the problem.

I wrote this in a view, and load the view in a window, the layer is showed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you turned your view 'self' a layer backed view? You will need to say

`self.wantsLayer = true`

before you can do any layer related manipulation.

Quoting [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/wantsLayer)-

> Setting the value of this property to true turns the view into a
>   layer-backed view—that is, the view uses a CALayer object to manage
>   its rendered content. Creating a layer-backed view implicitly causes
>   the entire view hierarchy under that view to become layer-backed.
>   Thus, the view and all of its subviews (including subviews of
>   subviews) become layer-backed. The default value of this property is
>   false.

Comment: Thanks very much, you really help me, it works.  But in my demo I didn't set the view wantsLayer be Yes, and default it's NO, why it worked either?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.